# Stop running the scripting after some steps then allow to work in windows later using enter key in keyboard continue the scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day !!
I'm new to python, I'm working in a mechanical software tool. To make some automation I came to python. Using Journal I have made a script. While running the script i need the scripting to pause and wait for the user commmand(use enter key in keyboard) to continue. In meanwhile I will work in my tool(software). Could you please guide me to make it easy using some commands.?

Comment: Please try to add ````input("Press Enter to continue")```` where you like to add it. Should work as required

Comment: @unityJarvis thanks for you comments, if i use the comment input("Press Enter to continue"), i get run time error message "RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin"

Comment: @vkv-onfire, My work is based on a 3D model, where I will rotate the model in 360°. I have a script that will shows the model crash, then the script will take a snap to make a report. After the model crash, I need to rotate the model in such direction and place it properly then I have to take snap. So I need to break the scripting inbetween and continue the same script after rotating my 3D model.

Comment: i think it not better to ask input in console but on the gui is better, is i told is right??

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want to work in gui. How do i get input from  gui?

Comment: @Aravind that i don't know but i will post answer when i get

Comment: You might be able to use the `pygame` library to wait for the keypress without having stdin

Comment: @Aravind can you tell which gui library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

or if you don't want to use text in input try to use getpass

```py
import getpass

getpass.getpass(prompt='enter to continue')#input
```

this will ask input but shouldn't write anything.
this can't be used because this works in console